# Best practices and issues on using git-tfs bridge

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

Well, I started this topic mainly to share the experience I had with git-tfs recently with the community.

If anybody has anything else to share - it will be helpful for me as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

About work in environment where several developers use git-tfs simultaneously. About commit identity caveats actually:
http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/first-git-tfs-usage-problems/

Is rebasing workflow with git-tfs possible?
http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/gittfs-rebasing-workflow-is-it-possible/

Not specifically git-tfs but affects it too. Problems with HOME directory on Windows:
http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/troubleshooting-gitextensions-home-directory/

Establishing central git repository to avoid redundant TFS round-trips: http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/how-to-establish-git-central-repository-for-working-against-tfs-with-git-tfs-bridge/

My environment for day-to-day work with git-tfs: http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/my-environment-for-day-to-day-work-with-git-tfs/

Answer (score 2):

And now you can easily manage TFS Branch with git-tfs : http://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki/Init-branch

Comment: That's a great thing, I'll try it definitely. Actually I'm already trying it and having some problems, so debug to the rescue. Thanks nevertheless, finding problems is often easier than writing thing in the first place.

Comment: I'm interested by your problems because it was quite eavily tested by at least 10 people on different project without problems. If it could help to improve...

Comment: I haven't had much time yet, but the problem is in the fact, that in our case branch in TFS is created from `$/A/B` to `$/A/B2` while git repository is cloned from subfolder, i.e. `$/A/B/C` - thus I want to see branch in git corresponding to `$/A/B2/C`. Auto-detection stucks [here](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/GitTfs.VsCommon/TfsHelper.PostVs2010.Common.cs#L31) and `No root changeset found` consequently. It seems not hard to fix if I didn't miss something crucial - just not anticipated possibility.

Comment: Yes, it's a case that could not be managed with init-branch. In fact the clone should be done from $/A/B (the trunk branch) and the init-branch will done with $/A/B2/ (or with the option --all) and it will work...

Comment: Yeah, but the TFS repository is poorly structured and `$/A/B` folder is large and contains many binary files which is not good for git. Moreover I just don't want to get several GB for nothing :)
Thus I would prefer to make some change to init-branch command logic. I'll make a pull request when I'm done and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Any gateway to move away from tfs for source control is awesome.

Comment: Totally agreed. Its a great relief to get normal SCM after using TFS for a while.